# Выполнить скрипт до загрузки css

Tags: javascript, jquery, загрузка

При загрузки страницы некоторые стили должны подгружаются из скрипта. Нужно сделать так, чтобы это происходило до загрузки основных css. Иначе загрузка страницы происходит скачком. В качестве костыля добавил прелоадер до срабатывания функции `$(document).ready(function()`, но возможно есть более грамотный вариант?

```
    .content {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
```

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
           ...
           
           $('.content').css({ 'transform' :  'scale(' + scale + ') }); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете подгружать основные CSS файлы после выполнения нужного вам кода внутри JS. Но это не избавит вас от сдвига макета полностью и увеличит скорость загрузки вашей страницы, что очень плохо отразится на UX и рейтинге сайта у поисковых систем, если вы весь основной СSS код будете грузить динамически. Лучше разбить ваш CSS на части и загружать динамически только тот кусок, который вызывает наибольший сдвиг макета, если это возможно с вашим кодом CSS.

```js
const cssId = 'main-css';  // здесь ID
if (!document.getElementById(cssId)) {
    const head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    const link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.id   = cssId;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'https://website.example/css/stylesheet.css';
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду думать в этом направлении.

Comment: Если вам пригодилось, отметьте как-то ответ, что он полезный был ) @Satkos